# Google Analytics Retrieve data

Tags: php, google-analytics

In one page on my personal site, I like to be able to see some data get from Google Analytics.

I like to have a list of all my site and the average visitor per week or per month over the current year

I have check some solution:

1. [Yahoo Pipe (look complicated)](http://video.yahoo.com/watch/5260536/13878389)
2. [Google Analytics PHP API class(look nice)](http://www.swis.nl/ga/)
3. [Google Analytics API (look official)](http://analytics.blogspot.com/2009/04/attention-developers-google-analytics.html)
4. [Dimension Analyzer for Google Analytics(look fancy)](http://www.google.com/ig/directory?type=gadgets&url=www.youcalc.com/apps/1238058348690/igoogle.xml)

So at this point, it have done my research, but none give me something i like to have. Getting a JSON from google would be nice. I will have to parse a XML maybe, but i like to see simpler solutions.

ANYthing would be nice too see

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The current version of the [Core Reporting API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference) supports this.

You can use the [PHP client](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/) to access the API. You'll need to register your project in the [API console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/) to obtain OAuth 2.0 client ID and secret.